# Detect mouse click on spark.components.List items, but ignore arrow keys

Tags: apache-flex, events, list, flex4, flex4.5

I have a custom component, containing a List displaying items from an XMLListCollection:

```
        [Bindable]
        private var _games:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
```

...

```
        <s:List itemRenderer="Game" dataProvider="{_games}"
          change="gameClicked(event)">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout />
            </s:layout>
        </s:List>
```

where XML data can look like this:

```
              <game id="0"/>
              <game id="9012">
                <user id="VK48058967" />
                <user id="MR14315189992643135976" />
                <user id="OK10218913103" />
              </game>
              <game id="9013">
                <user id="OK151358069597" />
                <user id="OK515549948434" />
              </game>
```

and the screenshot like this (representing joinable games with up to 3 players):

[image]

My problem is, that the **change**-Event listener is not only fired, when an item is clicked by mouse, but also when arrow keys on the keyboard are pressed:

```
        private function gameClicked(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
            var game:XML = event.currentTarget.selectedItem as XML;
            if (game == null)
                return;
            Alert.show("Clicked game: " + game.@id);
            dispatchEvent(new PrefEvent(PrefEvent.GAME_CLICKED, game.@id));
        }
```

Also if I click twice, only 1 mouse click will cause my custom event to be dispatched (because obviously there is no *change* between the items).

Does anybody please know, how to make my List only react to mouse clicks?

**UPDATE:**

Yes, I've tried using "change" event for the List before, but then I have the problem that it is fired, even if the List scrollbar is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, `yourList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)`?  Or you can just use the inline event in MXML. This listens for *all* clicks within the list.

You might want to just have a custom item renderer have it's own click handler and dispatch a custom event that bubbles up where you can listen for it up the display list, so it can be more specific.

Comment: No, I've tried adding CLICK listener to the List before and it would dispatch my custom event even when I click on the List scroll bar.

Comment: Yes, that's how click works.  You need to use a conditional to see if it's your item renderer being clicked: `if(event.target is Game)`, or just have your custom item renderer listen to clicks itself and dispatch that custom event itself.

Comment: For the 2nd option (adding "click" listener to the Game class) - how do I pass the custom PrefEvent 2 levels up (to the parent of my custom Lobby component, which holds the List)?

Comment: @Alexander set `bubbles=true` when creating the event and add the following metadata tag to your lobby: `[Event(name="gameClicked", type="com.farber.event.PrefEvent")]`

Comment: Add metadata to Lobby (containing the List) or to Game (the item renderer to be clicked)?